# Not numbering Executive summary in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I'm a beginner in Latex, and I want to use this software to do my report for uni.
However, I'm stuck on how to "not" number my executive summary in the table of contents.

### Attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\pagenumbering{alph}


\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \clearpage

    \section{Testing section}
    ...
    \clearpage

        \subsection{interesting}


\end{document}
```

Above is my attempt on creating the table of contents, however, I'm not sure where do I begin as I actually got this sets of codes from the internet.  If I do `/section{executive summary}` before table of contents, it wont be included in the TOC. However, if I did it afterwards, it will have numbers at the start.

[image]

So I was wondering how can I achieve something like this?

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Perhaps [Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Section_numbering) helps

Comment: @Harish Kumar You mean `\section*{executive summary}`

Comment: @HarishKumar: Yes, I tried that too, however, if I do that, it will not show in TOC.

Comment: @Jojo You need `\addcontentsline` for that. Any way you have an answer. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want chapters or sections without numbering you'll need write as
    `\chapter*{summary}` or as `\section*{summary}`
However if you write as such, it won't show in TOC. So you'll add that to TOC manually.

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Executive Summary}
```

Below is example code for your question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{alph}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section*{Summary}                                     %unnumbered section
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Executive Summary}      %manually add to TOC
\clearpage
\section{Testing section}
...
\clearpage
\subsection{interesting}


\end{document}
```

[image]